# Seach and delete item in list of dataframes

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

Lets say I creat a list of dataframes by:

```
import pandas as pd
lDfs = []

for i in range(0, 3):
    lDfs.append(pd.read_csv('SomeTable.csv')
```

then I have a list of 3 dataframes:

```
lDfs[0]
lDfs[1]
lDfs[2]
```

Lets say each dataframe has the following structure:

```
     Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
   0 2020-03-02,3355.330078,3406.399902,3257.989990,3338.830078,90017600
   1 2020-03-03,3355.520020,3448.239990,3354.300049,3371.969971,79445600
```

Now I want to search each dataframe in that list for a string pattern:

```
search = 'null'
```

and drop that row which includes that specific dataframe. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that 'null' was interpretet from pandas as NaN. So [DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=dropna#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) does the trick pretty easy:

```
for i in range(0, len(lDfs)):
    lDfs[i].dropna(inplace=True)
```